# Which plot is best for showing per percentage data?

Tags: python, visualization, data-visualization

i have a data set as shown below

```
Number of  Number
times      of 
donated    people
1         1885994
2         571213
3         298064
4         194252
5         140999
6         108091
7          86580
8          71330
9          59954
10         51590
11         44754
12         39711
```

and so on.. 
its around 100,000 data points. 
so, i wanted to try to plot a visualization, where i wanted to show how many percent of people donated 1 time, twice...and so on. 
which graph would be appropriate for this kind of data?

Comment: There are so many ways you could visualize this well.  One easy option would be a box plot, which statisticians like to use.  You could also do a bar chart with a line graph going through it.  It depends on what you really want to do.

Comment: One problem i have is that, towards the end, that is for "Number of times donated"  above 1000 till 100,000, the number of people donated is almost "1"

Comment: Why don't you just group 1000-100K donations in a single bucket, and then plot the other donation amounts separately?

Comment: how can i make buckets?

Comment: That depends on what language/tool you are using here.  What are you using?

Comment: i am using python

Comment: I don't know Python (at all), but I gave you an upvote.  Hopefully someone else can help you further.

Comment: I'd say a conventional distribution graph with number of "times donated" on the x axis vs frequency on the y axis. Since you have absolute counts, you will have to "bin" (or bucket  whatever you want to call) the values within an interval. Best is to allow users to dynamically change the bin size so they can look at the data with "fine/coarse grain" view. I'm a js guy, so here is an example from my own work: https://bl.ocks.org/ibrahimtanyalcin/4b99a23b09bf18123c0a1e440085af7d    Perhaps you can mash up something similar in python